# Struggling with definition of an orthonormal basis of $\mathcal{P}_2(\mathbb{R})$ and a possible contradiction

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

I've been constructing an orthonormal basis of  $\mathcal{P}_2(\mathbb{R})$ with respect to the inner product $$\langle p,q \rangle = \int_0^1p(x)q(x)dx.$$  Starting with the standard basis $\{1,x,x^2\}$ and using the Gram-Schmidt Procedure I have come up with the basis $$e_1 = 1,\;\; e_2 = 2\sqrt{3}(x - \tfrac{1}{2}),\;\; e_3=\tfrac{5}{6} +x - x^2.$$

However I am struggling with the condition that for an orthonormal basis $\langle e_j , e_k\rangle = 1$ if $j=k$ or else $\langle e_j ,e_k\rangle = 0$ for $j\neq k$.

Given the above inner product my defined $\Vert e_3\Vert = 1$ but $\langle e_1, e_3 \rangle = 1$.

I'm not quite sure how to resolve this. It seems like a contradiction.

edit: I am definitely wrong.  $\Vert e_3\Vert \neq 1.$ Thank you for pointing out my error!

Comment: It seems you did not do the Gram-Schmidt procedure correctly for the third vector. Maybe try again and show your steps?

Comment: I believe I calculated it correctly.  The problem can be a generalized away from the specific one I calculated.  If I have some appropriately calculated $e_3$, then by the definition of an orthonormal basis, $\langle e_3, e_3 \rangle = 1$. however because $e_1 = 1$ then $\langle e_1, e_3\rangle = \int_0^1 e^3 1 dx = \int_0^1 e^3dx = 1$.

Comment: From the theory of (some name here) polynomials, I would expect the correct $e_3$ to be a scalar multiple of $\frac{d^2}{dx^2} [ (x^2-x)^2 ] = 12x^2 - 12x + 2$.

Comment: If $e_3 = \lambda (12x^2 - 12x +2)$ for some scalar multiple, Then the norm doesn't work out correctly.

Comment: That 5/6 should be a 1/6. You computed the third one incorrectly. Then you need to normalize. The result is then $6 \sqrt{5} \left(x^2-x+\frac{1}{6}\right)$.

Comment: Thank you.  I realized the mistake that I am making.  it should be that $\int_0^1 e_3^2 = 1$, and $\int_0^1 e_3 = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake in two places.  First the calculation is wrong.  $e_3 = 6\sqrt{5}(x^2 -x +\frac{1}{6}).$

Second my logic was incorrect.  I kept looking for something that would have $\int_0^1 e_3 dx = 1$ which is incorrect.  I need to find $\langle e_3, 1 \rangle = \int_0^1 e_3 dx = 0$ and $\langle e_3, e_3\rangle = \int_0^1 e_3^2dx =1.$